# How to call next page in cursor pagination in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, pagination

```
  from rest_framework.pagination import CursorPagination


    # In API View
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        all_message = 
 GroupMessages.objects.filter(group_id=ChannelGroup.objects.filter(group_name=group_name).first())
        paginator = CursorPagination()
        result_page = paginator.paginate_queryset(all_message, request)
        serializer = GroupMessagesSerializer(result_page, many=True,context={'request': request})
        response = Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK
```

> I have implemented Cursor Pagination and i am getting response also.
> In PageNumberPagination We can manipulate our response via parameter
> in request url for eg ?page=1 or 2 but in cursor pagination if i want
> to test my pagination in postman how should i manipulate  it when i
> hit my url {{BaseUrl}}channel/getmessages/GeneralChannel/ i am getting
> 2 records but how can i fetch next two records which parameter should
> i pass or is there something else in Cursor pagination in order to do
> this

Comment: *which parameter should i pass* -  just pass `{{BaseUrl}}channel/getmessages/GeneralChannel/?page=2` in postman to get next two records

Comment: it would work for PageNumberPagination i am using CursorPagination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get next link from a function of `CursorPagination` class like this:

```
 paginator.get_next_link()
```

the result of this function is like this:

```
 {{BaseUrl}}channel/getmessages/GeneralChannel/?cursor=cD0yMDIyLTA3LTI3KzA1JTNBNDMlM0EyNy4xNDUwMDAlMkIwMCUzQTAw
```